# Is there a way in OCaml to declare in a record an integer which is an interval of some integers?

Tags: ocaml

I got stuck at this problem where I had to :
define a type date as a triple where the first component is a year represented as an
integer number, the second component is an integer number from the interval [1..12]
representing the month, and the last component represents a day with an integer
number.

```
type date = { year: int; month: int; day:int};;

{year = 2012; month = 12; day = 21};;
```

This works fine but for parameter month I need to have integers from 1 to 12 as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want for months only use a variant and enumerate all the month. You could do the same for day number but I would avoid it.

In case you wanted a more general notion like range type: you don't want that because month have either 30 or 31 days and February have 28-29 depending on leap year so it is dependent range... If this check is available which range do you want then ? The check you require is very specific: as an example I have only seen this in cpp with a extension and your forced to use int from the scope (so very unuseful). Because this extension required static int you couldn't really use for date. OCaml can't do that because all int are `int` not 30 nor 31. The usual workaround is create a function that take three int verify if they are in a valid range and return `date option` and also make it private from outside so you can't break the invariant. We call this smart constructor.

```
module SafeDate : sig
    type date = private { year: int; month: int; day:int}
    val create: int -> int -> int -> date option
end = struct
    type date = { year: int; month: int; day:int}
    let create year month day = if (* put formula/code to say if correct *) then Some{year; month; day} else None
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can prevent accidents.

Time and date libraries in OCaml (and elsewhere) usually ensure that the components of date objects fall in correct ranges without special type-system trickery.

In OCaml, a good solution may be to expose the fields of the date as read-only. This means the user of the module won't be able to create a record of such type using the notation `{year=...; month=...; day=...}`. This is achieved by providing an explicit module interface (.mli file) which declares the date type as `private`:

```
(* Date.mli *)
type t = private {
  year: int;
  month: int;
  day: int;
}

(** Create a date object if and only if given acceptable values *)
val create : year:int -> month:int -> day:int -> t option
```

The implementation (`Date.ml` file) is as usual. In particular, there's no `private` keyword in the type definition:

```
(* Date.ml *)
type t = {
  year: int;
  month: int;
  day: int;
}

let create ...
```

You can also get creative with this. For example, you can have the library safely expose fields derived from year/month/day, such as the number of days since the beginning of the year etc.